# DOCTYPE having influence on CSS?

Tags: html, css, doctype

I want to make a container of fixed size that will inside have an image (of unknown size). Then I want to make the image fit the container and be centered in it (both horizontally and vertically). What I came up with is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 500px; height: 375px; display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle">
      <img src="./Slideshow_files/Charles Bridge In Prague.jpg"
           style="max-width: 500px; max-height: 375px">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some images it works fine. However [this one](http://garydenness.posterous.com/charles-bridge-in-prague) (of precisely the size 500x375) makes the outer `div`'s height few pixels higher than 375px at the bottom (5px in Chrome, 4px in Opera). Why is that??

EDIT: Just added demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R3DHV/) (and another one with `display: table-row` and `display: table` elements around, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ApsDH)). In both cases the red background should not be visible; in Chrome & Opera it is.

Comment: First thing I though of when seeing the question's title was: IE. I was so angry one night because IE wasn't displaying my site properly. Later found out it was all because I missed the `DOCTYPE`.

Comment: Well, I didn't even get around to IE, but I have this problem both in Chrome and in FF. Is it normal that DOCTYPE has influence over CSS interpretation? (btw. I can fully understand your frustration, it also took me a while to figure out it's due to DOCTYPE).

Comment: Yes, it is normal. Changing the doctype will force the browser into different rendering modes which adjusts how the box model is interpreted. If you're working on a new site, I would highly recommend using the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` does not help; edited the question, added live example.

Comment: So glad I found this question. I was spending hours troubleshooting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix the problem by setting `display: block` or `vertical-align: top` (or `bottom`) on the `img`.

There are three different rendering modes:

- Quirks Mode
- Almost Standards Mode
- Standards Mode

Different doctypes trigger different rendering modes. See: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

In Standards Mode (with a triggering doctype), the default `vertical-align` is `baseline`.

In Quirks Mode (without a doctype), the default `vertical-align` is `bottom`.

This page explains it well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Comment: Works like a charm! Was the problem there because there is some sort of margin/spacing/padding after inline elements?